# How to handle null in Anorm

Tags: scala, anorm

I have a table with nullable column, and when query the null column, it threw error

```scala
 val row: List[(String,String)] = SQL("select top 10 Spare_Part part,Pricing_Category cat from Price_Point_Base")
                .as((str("part"))~ str("cat") map(flatten) *)
```

I checked the link
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaAnorm .

It only gives away to handle nullable column using something like

```scala
SQL("Select name,indepYear from Country")().map { row =>
  row[String]("name") -> row[Option[Int]]("indepYear")
}
```

But since `str("part")` is more compact than `row[String]("name")`, so I'd like to try using `str("part")`, but how to make `str("part")` works with nullable column?

Comment: You should consider updating. There was major updates since 2.0 and latest release 2.3 (2.3.4). Bugs fixed since cause the exception.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're reading a nullable column, you *really* should be binding it to an `Option[String]` to represent that it could be missing a value. Anorm will not convert it to `null`, rather it will throw an error.

```
val row: List[(Option[String], String)] = 
    SQL("select top 10 Spare_Part part,Pricing_Category cat from Price_Point_Base")
       .as( get[Option[String]("part") ~ str("cat") map(flatten) *)
```

This is messy however, and would get messier if you wanted to supply a default value for the `String`. We could make a re-usable parser that defaults `NULL` values to empty strings:

```
val parser: RowParser[(String, String)] = {
    get[Option[String]]("part") ~ get[Option[String]]("cat") map {
       case part~cat => (part.getOrElse(""), cat.getOrElse(""))
    }
}
```

And then apply it:

```
val row: List[(String, String)] = 
    SQL("select top 10 Spare_Part part,Pricing_Category cat from Price_Point_Base")
       .as(parser *)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/scala/anorm/SqlParser$.html) you'll see there is nothing that you're looking for. But looking at the [source code](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/anorm/src/main/scala/anorm/SqlParser.scala) I can assume that you can implement it yourself like this:

```
def strOpt(columnName: String)(implicit c: Column[Option[String]]): RowParser[Option[String]] =
  get[Option[String]](columnName)(c)
```

Didn't test it though but should likely work fine.